# ReactNative I18nManager is not forcing RTL on app launch

Tags: react-native, internationalization

When I use I18nManager.forceRTL(true) and manually restart the app with RNRestart package, everything works fine. But it only works if I restart the app. If I close and relaunch the app, layout reverts back to LTR. This is only happening in iOS.

How to force layout to be RTL in iOS?

```
ReactNative: 0.66.1
OS: macOS 12.0.1
Node: 18.2.0
CocoaPods: 1.11.3
Xcode: 13.1
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a [bug in React Native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/5d7fd00a8a088e27743b0d2bc6ff99bd7fe9285f) code. Just upgrade your React Native to a version >= 0.66.4 and everything works like a charm!